# Trying to enable docker api and now only getting Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://0.0.0.0:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, portainer

After following this guide, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/
specifically right after I entered this :

export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"

now when I run  docker ps

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://0.0.0.0:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Now when I try to do pretty much anything in docker nothing works, Portainer shows this

New Portainer installation
Your Portainer instance timed out for security purposes. To re-enable your Portainer instance, you will need to restart Portainer.

For further information, view our documentation.

Please help! How can I undo or replace the DOCKER_HOST env var to the correct setting if that's the issue?

OS is Opensuse Leap 15.3
Installed docker via convenience script
suseuser@komga:~> docker version
Client:
Version:           20.10.17-ce
API version:       1.41
Go version:        go1.17.11
Git commit:        a89b84221c85
Built:             Tue Jun  7 12:00:00 2022
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Context:           default
Experimental:      true
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://0.0.0.0:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: Well did you restart `portainer`? Almost every time I encountered this, I needed to start Docker Desktop.

Comment: Does `unset DOCKER_HOST` restore things to normal?  You should **never** attempt to start the Docker daemon with unencrypted network access on port 2375; it opens up unrestricted root access to anyone on the network and **it will get your system compromised**.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to reset to the default DOCKER_HOST value and was up and running again. I'm going to review the steps necessary to expose to daemon on port 2376 with TLS encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the DOCKER_HOST variable to the default value ( unix:///var/run/docker.sock ).

```
export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```